# После перехода из стартового окна в новое, потом обратно и снова в новое, перестают работать TextField и DatePicker

Tags: java, javafx

Первая программа не судите строго)

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/fxml/gui.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("СлужебкаХод");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1024, 768));
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

gui.fxml Две кнопки

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="768.0" maxWidth="1024.0" minHeight="768.0" minWidth="1024.0" prefHeight="768.0" prefWidth="1024.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.controller.ControllerGui">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="ButtonCreatSluschebka" layoutX="212.0" layoutY="136.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="242.0" text="Создать служебку" />
      <Button fx:id="ButtonSearchSluschebka" layoutX="606.0" layoutY="136.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="221.0" text="Поиск служебки" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

ControllerGui две кнопки

```
package sample.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import sample.Main;
import sample.WindowsHide;

public class ControllerGui {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private Button ButtonSearchSluschebka;

    @FXML
    private Button ButtonCreatSluschebka;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {

        WindowsHide wh = new WindowsHide();

        ButtonCreatSluschebka.setOnAction(event -> {
            ButtonCreatSluschebka.getScene().getWindow().hide();

            wh.hide("/sample/fxml/creat_sluschebka.fxml", "Создание служебки");

        });

        ButtonSearchSluschebka.setOnAction(event -> {
            ButtonSearchSluschebka.getScene().getWindow().hide();

            wh.hide("/sample/fxml/search.fxml", "Поиск служебки");

        });


    }
}
```

class  WindowsHide с методом hide который скрывает текущее окно и открывает новое.

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class  WindowsHide {
    public void hide(String nameFxml, String title) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(nameFxml));
        Parent root = loader.getRoot();
        try {
          root = loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1024, 768));
        stage.setTitle(title);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

По нажатию кнопки ButtonSearchSluschebka переходим в search.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="768.0" maxWidth="1024.0" minHeight="768.0" minWidth="1024.0" prefHeight="768.0" prefWidth="1024.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.controller.ControllerSearch">
   <children>
      <DatePicker fx:id="DataPikerOt" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="49.0" promptText="Выберите дату" />
      <DatePicker fx:id="DataPikerDo" layoutX="233.0" layoutY="49.0" promptText="Выберите дату" />
      <Button fx:id="buttonSearch" layoutX="433.0" layoutY="49.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="285.0" text="Найти служебки" />
      <Button fx:id="buttonOpenDoc" layoutX="748.0" layoutY="49.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="154.0" text="Открыть служебку" />
      <ListView fx:id="listDoc" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="160.0" prefHeight="551.0" prefWidth="666.0" />
      <Button fx:id="buttonBack" layoutX="506.0" layoutY="729.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="95.0" text="Назад" />
      <TextField fx:id="familKomu" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="89.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="174.0" promptText="Введите фамилию" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

ControllerSearch

```
package sample.controller;


import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import sample.WindowsHide;


public class ControllerSearch {

    String dataDo;
    String dataOt;
    String familyKomuLabel;

    @FXML
    private TextField familyKomu;

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker DataPikerOt;

    @FXML
    private Button buttonOpenDoc;

    @FXML
    private ListView<?> listDoc;

    @FXML
    private Button buttonSearch;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker DataPikerDo;

    @FXML
    private Button buttonBack;


    @FXML
    void initialize() {

        WindowsHide wh = new WindowsHide();

        DataPikerOt.setValue(LocalDate.now());
        DataPikerDo.setValue(LocalDate.now());

        buttonOpenDoc.setOnAction(event -> {

            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().edit(new File("//192.168.0.200/test/28.11.2019.12.44.48...docx"));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        });

        buttonSearch.setOnAction(event -> {

            familyKomuLabel = familyKomu.getText();

            try {
                dataDo = DataPikerDo.getValue().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"));
                dataOt = DataPikerOt.getValue().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"));

            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        });

        buttonBack.setOnAction(event -> {

            buttonBack.getScene().getWindow().hide();

            wh.hide("/sample/fxml/gui.fxml", "СлужебкаХод");
        });


    }
}
```

Не суть что делают элементы они еще не дописаны, интересует нажатие кнопки  buttonBack, переходим на стартовый экран, после этого если снова перейти в любое другое окно в нём перестают работать  TextField и DatePicker.Пробовал окна не скрывать а закрывать не помогает. Не могу понять в чем ошибка.... Пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: 1) Почему у вас в обоих классах используется stage.showAndWait(); ?
2) У вас в двух контроллерах 2 разных экземпляра класса WindowsHide Попробуйте покопать в этом направлении, вопрос слишком общий
3) Используйте уже наконец Scene Builder незаменимая вещь при работе с FX.

Comment: @PerfectVoyage Большое спасибо!